# Angular 2 merge same variable numbers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting numbers from database like this :

```
    getTeamPoints(team) {
console.log(team);
         let a = (<any>Object).values(team.tasks).reduce((total, entry) => total + entry.pt, 0);
        console.log('a = ',a)
    }
```

For each `number` I get `value` (only example not true values) :

```
a = 10;
a = 15;
a = 20;
a = 5;
a = 0;
```

**How to `merge` those `a` to one `number` which would be - `10+15+20+5+0 = 50` ?**

EDIT : console.log(team) :

```
{"members":{"-LT8U_zn5T9HuSlh03lw":{"name":"Andrius"}},"name":"Frontas","tasks":{"-LT8UbPIJMrR52P4hvHJ":{"name":"Jobas","pt":5},"-LT8UcOAvqPk_o3fUl7y":{"name":"Jobas2","pt":5}}}

{"members":{"-LT8UenQm-WzElOQhIrX":{"name":"Tomas"}},"name":"Backas","tasks":{"-LT8UfmIezqiMDv3WCpA":{"name":"Jobas3","pt":5}}}

{"members":{"-LT986cZrN6Q1sqIjMZF":{"name":"AAA"}},"name":"Tetas","tasks":{"-LT988EvCySLOutd5AVK":{"done":true,"name":"Jobas","pt":15},"-LT989cIEqr4ObqNyfiA":{"done":false,"name":"XX","pt":16}}}
```

Edit: looping through teams :

```
<mat-card-content *ngFor="let team of objectValues(project[2])>
    <h2 class="right-text">{{getTeamPoints(team)}}%</h2>
</mat-card-content>
```

edit: objectValues function :

```
  objectValues(obj) { 
if(obj){
  return Object.values(obj); 
}
```

console.log(teams) :

```
["teams",{"members":{"-LT8U_zn5T9HuSlh03lw":{"name":"Andrius"}},"name":"Frontas","tasks":{"-LT8UbPIJMrR52P4hvHJ":{"name":"Jobas","pt":5},"-LT8UcOAvqPk_o3fUl7y":{"name":"Jobas2","pt":5}}},{"members":{"-LT8UenQm-WzElOQhIrX":{"name":"Tomas"}},"name":"Backas","tasks":{"-LT8UfmIezqiMDv3WCpA":{"name":"Jobas3","pt":5}}},{"members":{"-LT986cZrN6Q1sqIjMZF":{"name":"AAA"}},"name":"Tetas","tasks":{"-LT988EvCySLOutd5AVK":{"done":true,"name":"Jobas","pt":15},"-LT989cIEqr4ObqNyfiA":{"done":false,"name":"XX","pt":16}}}]
```

Comment: So `a` is the total points for each team tasks? (I suggest you to change the variable name) How are you looping through teams?

Comment: for now a is each teams task point - want that a would be all points in one.

Comment: Your code just logs once... please post the full loop

Comment: My console.log is these a = 10, a = 15... - each of them is different number not an array.

Comment: You _probably_ have something like: `teams = [{...}, {...}]`. Then you are somehow looping through it (ex: `teams.forEach(team => { a = team.tasks...`). Only then you are using `console.log()`. Can you share the complete `teams` structure?

Comment: added console.log(team)

Comment: Ok, and how are you looping through each `team`? Is it a `*ngFor="let team of teams"`, or is it via for loop in your `inner.component.ts`?

Comment: added edit of html that I call for each team a function

Comment: The `getTeamPoints()` is working as I can see in your prints. First team should have `5+5 = 10` and it has

Comment: Those values I wrote just for example - Yes I get 5

Comment: @AndriusL. please post `team` as code not as image.

Comment: And I am getting each teams point summary - not all points seperately. (Now).

Comment: Do you want the sum of all teams inside `objectValues(project[2])`?

Comment: Done - posted as json.

Comment: Yes I want summary of all teams points in project[2]

Comment: Can you also share your `objectValues` function?

Comment: added objectValues(obj)

Comment: Change it to: `objectValues(obj) { return Object.values(obj || {}); }`

Comment: That didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your component like this:

```
<mat-card-content>
    <h2 class="right-text">
        {{ getProjectTeamsTotalPoints(objectValues(project[2])) }}
    </h2>
</mat-card-content>
```

And in your class add this method:

```
getProjectTeamsTotalPoints(teams): number {
    return teams.reduce((total, team) => {
        if (!team || !team.tasks) {
            return total;
        }
        return Object.values(team.tasks).reduce((pts, task) => {
            return pts + task.pt;
        }, total);
    }, 0);
}
```

Also update your objectValues function to always return an array:

```
objectValues(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj || {});
}
```

Basically, you reduce teams and for each team reduces their points, this way you get the total summary of the project.

Comment: console.log(teams) gives me array of each team

Comment: Please post that console in your question

Comment: added console.log(teams) json

Comment: team.tasks.reduce is not a function , Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Sorry, I've missed an `Object.values()` around `team.tasks`

Comment: My bad, I just forgot to use `total`, should work now

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your time ! It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in following way:

```
let a = 0;
a += (<any>Object).values(team.tasks).reduce((total, entry) => total + entry.pt, 0);
```

Comment: Why should he split it into two tasks?

Comment: that gives the same each point value for each task, not all summary.